SQL Server LIKE function using column values instead of string
Obviously the LIKE function doesn't work with actual column values.  Does anyone know either HOW to make it work? Or an alternative that could work?
Here is what I am trying to accomplish:
sfirstname   slastname       sccholdername
-----------------------------------------------
SCOTT        DREWYOR         KENT/MICHELLE
STEPHANIE    PIERSON         PIERSON/STEPHANIE
AMBER D      LINDSEY         MURRAY/AMBER
ALEXIA       SNELL           SNELL/D
JOHN         MESSING         MESSING/JOHN

In the above list, see how every instance the sccholdername has either the customers first or last name in it. EXCEPT for the Scott Drewyor. This could mean that the wrong credit card is attached to this persons account.
I need to be able to run a script that will identify every instance of this where the sccholdername column doesn't have either the sfirstname or slastname in it.
I've tried the basics like:
select *
from customers
where sccholddername not like sfirstname
   or sccholdername not like slastname

Definitely doesn't work.

not like '%' + sfirstname + '%' - you need wildcards for like to work.

So obviously the like function doesn't work with actual column values - not true at all. Column values work the same as any other string - you always need a wildcard.

BTW - is there a reason you haven't accepted an answer to any of your previous questions? Did none of the provided answers assist you? If not you should leave a comment saying as much.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

@BBE The question is quite unclear because the description doesn't match the attempt you have shown. First point is the incorrect syntax as pointed out by Dale. Next point is you use OR in your query, but according to your description, you rather need AND. And furthermore, even when fixing these two points, you will NOT exclude  AMBER D from the result as it doesn't appear in both first name or last name. So do you want to exclude her or not? See this sample fiddle

Please try the following solution based on tokenization.
SQL Server XQuery's Quantified Expression does all the magic: Quantified Expressions (XQuery)
Each word separated by space is considered a token, not the entire column value!
See row #3 as a concrete example of it. Its t1(x) contains the following value:
<root>
  <source>
    <r>AMBER</r>
    <r>D</r>
    <r>LINDSEY</r>
  </source>
  <target>
    <r>MURRAY</r>
    <r>AMBER</r>
  </target>
</root>

To find no match just uncomment the WHERE Result = 0 clause at the end.
SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, sfirstname VARCHAR(20), slastname VARCHAR(20), sccholdername VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @tbl (sfirstname, slastname, sccholdername) VALUES
('SCOTT',       'DREWYOR', 'KENT/MICHELLE'),
('STEPHANIE',   'PIERSON', 'PIERSON/STEPHANIE'),
('AMBER D',     'LINDSEY', 'MURRAY/AMBER'),
('ALEXIA',      'SNELL  ', 'SNELL/D'),
('JOHN',        'MESSING', 'MESSING/JOHN');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator1 CHAR(1) = SPACE(1)
   , @separator2 CHAR(1) = '/';

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT * 
        , x.value('some $r in /root/source/r/text()
            satisfies $r = /root/target/r/text()', 'BIT') AS Result
    FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root>' + 
        '<source><r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(sfirstname + @separator1 + slastname, @separator1, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></source>' + 
        '<target><r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(sccholdername, @separator2, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></target>' + 
        '</root>' AS XML)) AS t1(x)
)
SELECT * FROM rs
--WHERE Result = 0;

Output



id
sfirstname
slastname
sccholdername
Result




1
SCOTT
DREWYOR
KENT/MICHELLE
0


2
STEPHANIE
PIERSON
PIERSON/STEPHANIE
1


3
AMBER D
LINDSEY
MURRAY/AMBER
1


4
ALEXIA
SNELL
SNELL/D
1


5
JOHN
MESSING
MESSING/JOHN
1





The below query uses a nested structure.
The TRIM function eliminates any leading or trailing spaces. For sfirstname and slastname,
it extracts only the first word. For example, from ‘AMBER D’, it takes ‘AMBER’ as the first name.
Similarly, sccholdertname is split into first and last names. The outer query then compares sfirstname
with sccholderfirstname or slastname with sccholderlastname

SELECT * 
FROM
(SELECT 
    LEFT(TRIM(sfirstname), CHARINDEX(' ', TRIM(sfirstname) + ' ') - 1) AS sfirstname,
    LEFT(TRIM(slastname), CHARINDEX(' ', TRIM(slastname) + ' ') - 1) AS slastname,
    sccholdertname,
    REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(TRIM(sccholdertname)), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(TRIM(sccholdertname)) + '/') - 1)) AS sccholderfirstname,
    LEFT(TRIM(sccholdertname), CHARINDEX('/', TRIM(sccholdertname) + '/') - 1) AS sccholderlastname
FROM 
    Customers) A
WHERE
    sfirstname <> sccholderfirstname
    OR slastname <> sccholderlastname


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Below query should be able to help you identify the sccholdername where firstname and lastname is not correct and wrong credit card is attached to the person's account.
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    customers
WHERE LEFT(sccholdername, CHARINDEX('/', sccholdername) - 1) <> sfirstname 
AND RIGHT(sccholdername, LEN(sccholdername) - CHARINDEX('/', sccholdername)) <> slastname;

https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=ede9bb6a-1221-403e-a75b-2bcea143456e

No, the query is not able, it's just invalid, see db<>fiddle. Please try out possible solutions before writing an answer. I guess the last condition should be RIGHT(sccholdername, LEN(sccholdername) - CHARINDEX('/', sccholdername)) <> slastname , then at least the query is valid. But it will still not produce the result OP requested.

This is working. Please check https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=ede9bb6a-1221-403e-a75b-2bcea143456e

Add the output and fiddle link to your answer... Like the other answer has
